# An 80's-90's sci-fi cartoon about adventuring on the planet's surface with a female reptilian scientist character and an army of stone "robots"

Tags: story-identification, space, animated-series

I saw this cartoon (might be an animated series) a long time ago, like 20 years or so and my memories about it might have slipped away a bit. Some of the details may not belong to a single piece of fiction.

1. It's a sci-fi cartoon or animated series. There were spaceships, main plot took place on the surface of the planet and there was a city under a force field dome.
2. There was an antagonist, don't remember his name. He had an army of that seemed like orange golems of orange stone. They're capable of flying and shooting yellow lasers from their fingerless hands. They had no head and they had something that seemed to be a an eye on the chest.
3. The antagonist had a partner. She was an anthropomorphic reptile scientist walking in white scientist robe or jacket. She wanted to find a cure of some sorts for her kind, and she got it by betraying the antagonist while helping the main characters. She helped them, they gave her the cure and then she flew away.
4. The city under the dome in a desert. The city's inhabitants seemed to be showing the city to the main characters, leading them to some kind of utility room where they were ambushed by rocks that turned out to be said golems.
5. There also was a mercenary with blue skin hired by the antagonist. He's been flying on a single-seat spaceship.

That's all. I thought that kind of setting could be a part of *The Masters of the Universe* franchise. I also remember an anime with some obscure similarities to the subject and it was related to a giant robot. Looking at pictures of anime pieces that have these robots in them, I think it's *Mazinger Z*, but it doesn't seem that *Mazinger Z* had any relation to extraterrestrial sci-fi. I also looked at *Bravestar* and *Darkstar* and things like that, but haven't had a luck getting what I'm searching for.

Comment: Some parts, robots, blue skin, sound like *Gandahar*, but the robots are metal, more humanoid, and turn people into stone with the blasts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Point 3 makes it sound like the 1996 cartoon version of Flash Gordon. The main antagonist, named Ming the Merciless, had an anthropomorphic lizard scientist as a partner/underling. Her name was Sulpha, and she wore a white lab coat. She sometimes helped the heros because she hated Ming, but she was villainous in her own right.
There were also lots of space ships, as per point 1. I am not certain about the rest of the points, but they sound like Flash Gordon type settings.
The whole thing is available on the Plex app, if you have that.

Check 10:18 for Sulpha, as well as a grey skinned mercenary that may be the the guy from point 5.

Here are the rock warriors as described in point 2:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's it! I almost started to think I made this cartoon up :D